# DOMImplementation - проверка версии DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Хотел посмотреть, какой результат получу при запуске следующего интерфейса DOM 3

```
alert(DOMImplementation.hasFeature("Core", "3.0"));
```

Однако ни при использовании Microsoft Edge, ни при использовании Google Chrome никакой реакции не получил.

Поддерживается ли этот интерфейс DOM 3 браузерами, или я что-то делаю не правильно?

Comment: [_It is deprecated and modern browsers return true in all cases._](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/hasFeature)

Comment: Похоже именно этот метод deprecated

Comment: @Grundy Когда же он успел стать deprecated? У меня  true не выдается.

Comment: Ага, понял, похоже в данном случае неверное использование: `DOMImplementation` - это _интерфейс_, поэтому нельзя обратиться `DOMImplementation.hasFeature`. Для получения экземпляра этого интерфейса, нужно использовать [document.implementation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/implementation)

Comment: @Grundy Напишите это в своем ответе. Я только не понимаю, почему используется document, а не window

Comment: Добавил ответ. В документ его поместили скорее всего потому, что `D` в `DOM` означает документ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DOMImplementation](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#domimplementation) - это один из предоставляемых браузером интерфейсов, поэтому для вызова функций описываемых в этом интерфейсе необходим объект, который этот интерфейс реализует.

Такой объект определен в [интерфейсе Document](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#document)

```
interface Document : Node {
  [SameObject] readonly attribute DOMImplementation implementation;
  ...
}
```

Поэтому вызов должен выглядеть так:

```
alert(document.implementation.hasFeature("Core", "3.0"));
```

Но если обратиться к [описанию этого метода](https://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#dom-domimplementation-hasfeature):

> The `hasFeature()` method **must** return true.
>
> **Note:** `hasFeature()` originally would report whether the user agent claimed to support a given DOM feature, but experience proved it was not nearly as reliable or granular as simply checking whether the desired objects, attributes, or methods existed. As such, it should no longer be used, but continues to exist (and simply returns true) so that old pages don't stop working.